# PHP echo does not print values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to solve an issue in php, but I did not find a solution yet.

This is the code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pl_scored_goal, (pl_scored_goal - @min) as diff FROM hb_games");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo $row['diff'];
}
```

The `$sql` query works properly on `phpMyAdmin` and it shows the results `0 -9`, but the echo above does not work.

I also tried to find out the possible errors:

```
print_r($sql)//result Resource id #9
var_dump($row['diff']//result NULL NULL
```

I do not understand why I cannot echo the values.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and see what you are getting.

Comment: @Daniel my God, people, use PDO... Why are you struggling with deprecated functions?? I really DO NOT understand you... PHP 3 is LOOOONG GONE! Get over it!

Comment: var_dump($row) shows:array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "26" ["pl_scored_goal"]=> string(2) "26" [1]=> NULL ["diff"]=> NULL } array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "22" ["pl_scored_goal"]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> NULL ["diff"]=> NULL }

Comment: what is supposed to be @min?

Comment: see `diff` is containing `NULL`

Comment: also you can use `echo $row[0];` and `echo $row[1];`

Comment: actually, that does not matter! everything works fine, except for the query who return NULL as diff... it's damn obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, try (pl_scored_goal - COALESCE(@min, 0)) as diff

Comment: Which would mean that @min is not existing.

Comment: what could be if pl_scored_goal comes from a table of scored goals retrieved by player id...

Comment: :)) you sound like those guys from customer support: "Unfortunately, we cannot assist you at the moment... Please try again later!"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pl_scored_goal, (pl_scored_goal - @min) as diff FROM hb_games");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
echo"
".$row->diff;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sapan, unfortunately the script does not print the values :-(